# Polarized Cross Section and the Spin Density Matrix

Tags: particle-physics, density-operator, scattering-cross-section

I am trying to calculate the spin density matrix for the following process ($t$-Quark on shell):

[image]

My first method is to split the process into a production and a decay.I have determined the polarized production cross section $\sigma_P^{pol.}$ as well as the polarized decay width $\Gamma_t^{pol.}$. The next step in this method would be to determine the production spin density matrix and the decay spin density matrix.What I do not know how.

The second method is the determination of the cross section over the full process by means of the Narrow Width Approximation. (Is in progress)

At the end I should get the spin density matrix by a comparison between the two calculation methods. Now comes my problem. I just don't know how the spin density matrix comes into play here in general. I know that for a spin-$1/2$ particle the density matrix $\rho$ is a $2×2$ matrix and found that:

$$\rho = \frac{1}{2}[\mathbb{I}+\hat{P_i}\hat{\sigma_i}]$$ (I hope this is right)

where $\hat{P_i}$ is the polarization vector and $\hat{\sigma}_i$ are the pauli matrices.

But how does this relate to what I have already calculated? What am I missing? The textbooks don't get me anywhere either. Can someone give me a hint or some literatur?

As a bachelor student, I unfortunately have not had any quantum field theory or introductory lectures on higher particle physics and have to acquire the knowledge by myself.